# Как подключиться к базе данных Oracle используя FireDac?

Tags: delphi, oracle, firedac

К базе данных `Oracle` необходимо подключиться удаленно. На рабочем компьютере установлен только клиент. В среде `Delphi` нашел компоненты `FireDac`, но драйвер не могу выбрать у компонента `TFDConnection` т.к его нет в списке.

[image: Настройка FDConnection]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Среда разработки `Embarcadero RAD Studio 10.2`

Comment: [Connect to Oracle Server (FireDAC)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Connect_to_Oracle_Server_(FireDAC))

Comment: @zed это я видел . Скопировал файлы к себе в папку . Но компонента TFDPhysOracleDriverLink у меня нет в палитре . Так и не разобрался что с этим делать

Comment: А юнит `FireDAC.Phys.Oracle` есть? Если ни того, ни другого нету, значит у вас FireDAC установился криво. У вас официальная Enterprise редакция Delphi?

Comment: @zed Редакция `RAD Studio Professional` . Да , официальная. Я так понимаю эта редакция не позволяет работать с Ораклянной базой. Или я не прав?. Фала  `FireDAC.Phys.Oracle` не нашел.

Comment: Да, не позволяет. Oracle только в Enterprise: https://www.embarcadero.com/products/rad-studio/firedac